# will git record the time when I write the code? or only record the time when I git add

Tags: git

I want to know when I writing the code and will git record the time I write which line of code. Or It just record the time when I `git add .` and `git commit`.

Comment: git records the time you `git commit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you make a commit for every line of code you write (which would be incredibly pedantic), Git will only record the time in which you've committed the actual code into the repository - that is, only when you've run `git commit` successfully.

Comment: So git add won't record the time?

Comment: You've only staged it at that point, and it's not part of the formal history of your project yet.  So no, I wouldn't believe that it would.

Comment: @yongho `git add` will update your `.git/index` file; as such you could probably take a look at the modification date of the file. But this will only inform you about the last modification and `git add` isn't the only command which touches `.git/index` so there is no guarantee that this was truly the time `git add` was used.